# Consulta editar con PDO

Tags: php, pdo

```
**Este es el error que me tira no se si tengo bien hecho el codigo**
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in D:\xampp\htdocs\proyectohelados\controladores\editar_ventas.php:19 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\proyectohelados\controladores\editar_ventas.php(19): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in**

*este es mi codigo PHP con PDO*

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $producto = $_POST['producto'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eladeria", "root", "");
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db=$conexion;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("update ventas set producto=:producto,cantidad=:cantidad,precio=:precio ,fecha_venta=:fecha where id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":producto",$producto);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cantidad",$cantidad);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precio",$precio);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha_venta",$fecha);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
    $stmt->execute();

}
?>
```

*Este es mi formulario*

```
<form id="formulario" method="post">
                                                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Id</label>
                                                        </i>
                                                        <input type="text" name="id" readonly value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  name="producto" class="form-control validate">

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Producto</label>
                                                        </i>
                                                        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" name="producto" class="form-control validate">

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Cantidad</label>
                                                        </i>
                                                        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" name="cantidad" class="form-control validate">

                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Precio</label>
                                                        </i>
                                                        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" name="precio" class="form-control validate">

                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
                                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Fecha de la
                                                                venta</label>
                                                        </i>
                                                        <input type="date" id="orangeForm-name" name="fecha" class="form-control validate">

                                                    </div>

                                                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba corrigiendo los siguientes detalles

1. Para validar el tipo de petición si es GET o POST; debes hacerlo leyendo la variable global `$SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`
2. En la sentencia UPDDATE tienes `fecha_venta=:venta` pero en el bindParam tienes `$stmt->bindParam(":fecha_venta",$fecha);` es decir los marcadores de posición no coinciden

Por lo tanto tu código debería quedar así

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $producto = $_POST['producto'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eladeria", "root", "");
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db=$conexion;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("update ventas set producto=:producto,cantidad=:cantidad,precio=:precio ,fecha_venta=:fecha where id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":producto",$producto);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cantidad",$cantidad);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precio",$precio);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me servio mucho

Answer (score 1):

Hola tienes que hacer esta corrección en tu código:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":fecha_venta",$fecha);
```

por esto

```
$stmt->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
```

esto te podria servir para como idea:

```
<?php
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eladeria", "root", "");
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db=$conexion;
$id = "";
$producto ="";
$precio = "";
$cantidad ="";
$fecha="";

if ($_POST) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $producto = $_POST['producto'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];


    $stmt = $db->prepare("update ventas set producto=:producto,cantidad=:cantidad,precio=:precio ,fecha_venta=:fecha where id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":producto",$producto);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cantidad",$cantidad);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precio",$precio);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fecha",$fecha);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
    $stmt->execute();

}
?>
<form id="formulario" method="post">
    <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Id</label>
        </i>
        <input type="text" name="id"   value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="producto" class="form-control validate">

    </div>
    <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Producto</label>
        </i>
        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" value="<?php echo $producto; ?>" name="producto" class="form-control validate">

    </div>

    <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Cantidad</label>
        </i>
        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>" name="cantidad" class="form-control validate">

    </div>


    <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Precio</label>
        </i>
        <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>" name="precio" class="form-control validate">

    </div>


    <div class="md-form mb-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Fecha de la
                venta</label>
        </i>
        <input type="date" id="orangeForm-name" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" name="fecha" class="form-control validate">

    </div>
<div class="md-form mb-5">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Enviar">
</div>  
</form>
```

Saludos ....